# How to print characters? Error -This format specifier is invalid - FORTRAN (Windows)

Tags: fortran

I was building a Fortran Code on Visual Studio 19, I wanted to understand the line above the print statement to understand what exactly are the inputs provided to calculate RtAeroPwr, so I tried printing small parts of it to understand what inputs are exactly provided to have a broad understanding. But when I did try to build this, the following is the error:

```
error#6252: This format specifier is invalid.
```

How can I print the values used?

Part of the code where the error message appears is as follows:

```
tmp = matmul( u%HubMotion%Orientation(:,:,1), moment )
m%AllOuts( RtAeroPwr ) = m%BEMT_u(indx)%omega * m%AllOuts( RtAeroMxh )
print m%AllOuts( RtAeroMxh ), m%AllOuts, m%BEMT_u
```

Comment: Please add any code as text rather than an image. However, from the image it looks like you need to understand the very basics of using the `print` statement. The linked question gives some detail of one approach, but really Stack Overflow isn't the best place to try to learn the fundamentals of a language: you'll probably make much better progress using a dedicated learning resource such as tutorials or books.

Comment: `tmp = matmul( u%HubMotion%Orientation(:,:,1), moment )

m%AllOuts( RtAeroPwr ) = m%BEMT_u(indx)%omega * m%AllOuts( RtAeroMxh )

print m%AllOuts( RtAeroMxh ), m%AllOuts, m%BEMT_u`
This is a snippet of this code. I primarily don't have to learn the entire Fortran it's just how to check these values used. Rest is already done. Thanks for the reply @francescalus

Comment: As the linked question covers, you should be able to make a good start with simply `print *, m%AllOuts( RtAeroMxh ), m%AllOuts, m%BEMT_u`.

Comment: Got the following error: 
`error #5514: A derived type I/O list item that contains a pointer or an allocatable component (THETA) requires a user-defined derived-type input/output procedure. `